# save fragment from getting destroyed or hiding and change badge number also

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-volley

i have a main activity in which i have loaded couple of fragments when i change the orientation, the current fragment is destroyed and default fragment is loaded and i also want to change the badge number from fragment but i have no idea how to do it. please help me to save the state of fragment.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar;
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_nav_bar);

    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_white));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.mynavigation);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.mydrawer);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.my_bottom_menu);
    badgeDrawable = bottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.cart);

    badgeDrawable.setNumber(cartitems);


    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);


    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, new home()).commit();
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home:

                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, new home()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.order:

                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, new order()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.cart:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, new Cart()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                    break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Create a fragment guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-programmatic):

> note that the fragment transaction is only created when `savedInstanceState` is `null`. This is to ensure that the fragment is added only once, when the activity is first created. When a configuration change occurs and the activity is recreated, `savedInstanceState` is no longer `null`, and the fragment does not need to be added a second time, as the fragment is automatically restored from the `savedInstanceState`.

So you need to wrap any calls that set your initial state in `if (savedInstanceState == null)`:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, new home()).commit();
}
```

Note that same guide also explains how you can [add your initial fragment via XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-xml), which does this same thing for you and allows you to remove that `beginTransaction` from your `onCreate()` entirely:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mycontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name=".home" />
```